# Reading text files when item is clicked in ListView- Android

Tags: android

I'm deveoping an Android app for listing songs. When any song( item in the ListView) is clicked, its lyrics( a Text File should be displayed). When I click on the ListView item, it starts the new activity but displays nothing. I'm not sure what's causing this. Is it because I'm not passing the bundles or using them correctly? The problem is it can't pass the if statement( in the second activity) to read the txt file. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.Here's the code

First Activity

```
        public class ListOfSongs extends Activity {

        private ListView songsListView;
        private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_of_songs);
            final String SONG_ONE = "songOne";
            final String SONG_TWO = "songTwo";
            // Find the ListView resource.
            songsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listofsongs);

            // Create and populate a List of songs names.
            final String[] songs = new String[] { "Song1", "Song2", "Song3",
                    "Song4", "Song5", "Song6", "Song7", "Song8" };
            ArrayList<String> songtList = new ArrayList<String>();
            songtList.addAll(Arrays.asList(songs));

            // Create ArrayAdapter using the songs list.
            // Each row in the ListView will be a TextView. The TextView is defined
            // in another file (res/layout/simplerow.xml).
            listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow,
                    songtList);
            // Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.
            songsListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

            songsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {

                    Intent startReadingTheLyrics = new Intent(ListOfSongs.this,
                            ReadingTheLyrics.class);

                    if (position == 0) {
                        System.out.println("Position zero");
                        startReadingTheLyrics.putExtra("song1", SONG_ONE);
                        startActivity(startReadingTheLyrics);
                    } else if (position == 1) {
                        System.out.println("Position one");
                        startReadingTheLyrics.putExtra("song2", SONG_TWO);
                        startActivity(startReadingTheLyrics);
                    }

                }
            });
        }
```

Second Activity:

```
    public class ReadingTheLyrics extends Activity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.simplerow);

            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String song1 = intent.getStringExtra("song1");
            String song2 = intent.getStringExtra("song2");
    //It's not able to pass the if statement to be able to read the text file
            if (intent.hasExtra(song1)) {
                try {
                    // create an Input stream to read the file
                    InputStream songOne = getResources().openRawResource(
                            R.raw.songone);
                    // assign it to a string the method is down below
                    String lyricOne = inputStreamToString(songOne);
                    // get the TextView
                    TextView lyricTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rowTextView);
                    // set the text
                    lyricTextView.setText(lyricOne);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("DEBUG", "InputStreamToString failure");
                }

            }// end of reading song one

            if (intent.equals(song2)) {
                System.out.println("Chachawee mo bentna");
                try {
                    // create an Input stream to read the file
                    InputStream songTwo = getResources().openRawResource(
                            R.raw.songtwo);
                    // assign it to a string the method is down below
                    String lyricTwo = inputStreamToString(songTwo);
                    // get the TextView
                    TextView lyricTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rowTextView);
                    // set the text
                    lyricTextView.setText(lyricTwo);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("DEBUG", "InputStreamToString failure");
                }

            }// end of reading song one

        }// end of onCreate method

        private String inputStreamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
            // create a buffer
            StringBuffer sBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            DataInputStream dataIO = new DataInputStream(is);
            String strLine = null;

            while ((strLine = dataIO.readLine()) != null) {
                sBuffer.append(strLine + "\n");

            }
            dataIO.close();
            is.close();
            return sBuffer.toString();
        }
        }
```

activity_list_of_songs.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    tools:context=".ListOfSongs" >

  <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
      android:textColor="@android:color/white"  
      android:textSize="25sp"
      android:id="@+id/listofsongs">  
    </ListView> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

simplerow.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/rowTextView" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:padding="10dp"
 android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
```

Comment: Could you post your .xml?

Comment: I just posted both xml files. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The if statement is incorrect here.

```
  Intent intent = getIntent();
        String song1 = intent.getStringExtra("song1");
        String song2 = intent.getStringExtra("song2");
//It's not able to pass the if statement to be able to read the text file
        if (intent.hasExtra(song1))
```

When you do `intent.getStringExtra("song1")`, `song1="SongOne"` and this not the key available in your Intent, so `intent.hasExtra()` returns false and the if condition is not satisfied.
For more info on Intents refer here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#hasExtra(java.lang.String)

Comment: Thank you,nikhil.thakkar. Problem Solved.